# Calling code Behind method With void return type using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

Hi i'm trying to call a code behind method using jquery. But that method should not return any value. I created web method and calling it. My method is like this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "Model/Services/Information.asmx/TestingExport",
                data: JSON.stringify(empno),
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.ok) {
                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').empty();
                        $('#ExportEmpInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'Data Has been Exported to Excel successfully ' + '</b></p>');
                    }
                else {

                    $('#ExportEmpInfo').empty();
                    $('#ExportEmpInfo').append('<p><b>' + 'Exporting to Excel Failed' + '</b></p>');

                }


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('TextStatus:' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        })
```

But the Testing Export method will call other methods which will finally call a method which will export data to excel format. In the final method there is part of code  which is used to export data to excel

```
response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Charset = "";
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

I guess this is having in conflict with as that of the reponse.ContentType mentioned in Json and is throwing "ParseError Object Error". It is throwing error. Please help me how to call a function which doesn't return any value back. If return type is necessary then I can return any value but how to handle the error thrown by response.ContentType

My Export to Excel function is

```
public static void ExportToExcel(HttpResponse response, DataSet ds)
        {
            try
            {
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.Charset = "";
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {

                    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

                    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

                    stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                    htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
                    dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[i];
                    dg.DataBind();
                    dg.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
                    response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                }
                response.Flush();
                response.Close();
                response.Write("");

            }
```

The control is going through all this code with out any error but it is not generating excel sheet as it is generated when called through normal code behind method instead of calling from web method.

Comment: If you don't need to return any data, then why is the response being manipulated in the first place?

Comment: Those response statements will do nothing when calling your method from ajax.( Except cause you problems.)

Comment: The function which i'm calling from script won't return any value but it will call other functions which will call a function which generates excel file so the response code is the code that is used for generating excel file.

Comment: @user2864496: Those response statements have nothing to do with creating an Excel file.

Comment: if we wont use those response statements then how will we specify the extension of the file to be stored using  response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Comment: Is your goal to invoke a method on the server from the client that generates and saves an Excel file somewhere on the server? Or are you trying to invoke a method that forces the user to download the Excel file on the client side? The latter is not possible with AJAX; and you wouldn't need AJAX for it anyway. A regular GET/POST to the server in conjunction with the appropriate response headers would force the browser to show a "Save as" dialog for the response without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Cory I got it. But I want to pass a value as parameter to the function which i'm calling up on clicking. this parameter is used to fetch data from database which is later passed to Export to Excel function where it is converted to excel. That is why I want to call function from script so that i can access the value which i want to pass using attr property of jquery

Comment: @user2864496: But do you want to actually consume the response? Also, I don't see any Excel file being generated whatsoever; only a `DataGrid` rendered to HTML and written to the response. Excel files are binary or based on XML; neither of which is happening here.

Answer (score 2):

The right solution should be removing the code that sets the response if no response is expected. However if this is not possible (I assume the "final class" is not used right here), then this line

```
dataType: "json"
```

tells jQuery that it should expect the response in JSON format. However it is receiving something different and fails to parse it, throwing the error. Just remove this line.

Comment: Hai Andrei I removed dataType: "json" now it is not throwing any error but it is not generating excel file. It is going through the function which generates excel file but it is not showing any prompt which is generally showed with options open save cancel for excel sheet.  My export to excel function is mentioned above in the question

Comment: @user2864496 That sounds like a separate issue. I would start a new question and clearly explain your new problem as well as what investigative steps you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method TestingExport has return type as void. Then no need to keep the success: function(resp){if(resp.ok)....You can remove resp as parameter and checking it in if too. If you want to keep it, instead checking resp.ok, check !(resp===null).